# DRUPAL_UID is not set

Tags: jquery, drupal, cookies

I am including the jquery library:

```
function zenbws_preprocess_html() {
    drupal_add_library('system', 'jquery.cookie');
}
```

The assumption is that the cookie is going to be set but I cannot see `DRUPAL_UID` in the browser cookie list. Plus `var cookie_value = jQuery.cookie("DRUPAL_UID");` does not return anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: Drupal sets no such cookie

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually through your template.php file like you are with the library...

```
drupal_add_js(array('userid' => $user->uid), 'setting');
```

Access in javascript using:

```
Drupal.settings.userid
```

If you REALLY want it in a cookie, you can then use your code to set it:

```
jQuery.cookie('userid', Drupal.settings.userid, { expires: 7 });  // Lasts 1 week
```

And access it:

```
jQuery.cookie('userid');
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10186452/863380).

Create a new module with [hook_init](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) implementation.

```
function [YOUR_MODULE]_init()
{
    global $user;
    drupal_add_js(array('user_js_uid' => $user->uid), 'setting');
}
```

You now have the user uid inside the javascript variable `user_js_uid`.